# 1 day Schengen overstay FRA

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

I'm traveling to France from South Africa on the 19th of August, I'll only be in the Schengen area on the 20th of August, and depart the Schengen area on the 20th of September.

My visa states that days of stay is: 30 days

My visa expires in October.

Is there a chance of getting in trouble for the 1 day overstay?

Comment: If you're unlucky the airline won't let you board the plane in South Africa when you don't have a ticket to take you out of the Schengen area within the validity of your visa.

Comment: 20th of August to 20th of September is 32 days. You need to change one of your flights to shorten your stay within the allowed 30-day limit. Remember that that day you arrive and the day you depart are counted as full days. Also remember that the airline may be even more restrictive and count the day you depart from South Africa and the day you arrive back there if they feel like it. And add some buffer, delays and cancellations do happen.

Comment: That's actually a *2* day overstay, for the record. Each day that you spend (even partially) in the Schengen area counts.

Comment: You’d also have to declare the overstay in any future visa applications that ask about them (Schengen doesn’t, AFAIK), but the UK does, for example.

Comment: Your overstay should be recorded, and you will have (a lot) more difficulty in getting further visas from France at the very least, possibly the whole Schengen Area. It's definitely not worth it.

Comment: @jcaron another option, if the visa is valid for 2 or multiple entries, would be to leave the Schengen area in the middle of the trip and return on the third day after leaving, or later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some chance that you will have to pay a fine on departure.

There is a high probability that the overstay will be a problem with your next Schengen visa application.

There is a high probability that the overstay will be a problem with other visa applications.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the flight, don't want to take the chance.